# How to loop through the date range and add entries on each date on Entity Framework Core (.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building a exam management system for my college project using ASP.NET Core MVC6. Below is my Exam Model

```cs
public class ExamModel
{
    [Key]
    public int s_no { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateOnly start_date { get; set; }
    public DateOnly end_date { get; set; }
    public string sem_year { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("pid")]
    public virtual ProgramModel ProgramModel { get; set; }  
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExamDetailsModel> ExamDetailsModels { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my exam details model:

```cs
public class ExamDetailsModel
{
    [Key]
    public int s_no { get; set; }
    public int full_marks { get; set; }
    public int pass_marks { get; set; }
    public DateOnly exam_date { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly time { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("cid")]
    public virtual CourseModel CourseModel { get; set; }  
    public int cid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("eid")]
    public virtual ExamModel ExamModel { get; set; }  
    public int eid { get; set; }    
}
```

I have successfully finished the add operation of exam model with the code below

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddExam(ExamModel examModel, string start_date, string end_date)
{
    examModel.start_date = DateOnly.Parse(start_date);
    examModel.end_date = DateOnly.Parse(end_date);
    _context.ExamModels.Add(examModel);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The screenshot of output:
[image: Screenshot]

Now, what I want to do is when the user clicks the button add detail (see the screenshot). I want each date from start to end be looped and displayed with a form in the right side of each date from where user will be able to input course, time, full marks, pass marks and other things and submit all of them them with one click and the data will be automatically stored in ExamDetails Model.

If it's possible please show me how, if its not possible please show me alternate methods to do so. I'm stuck please help.

Comment: Maybe add an "ExamDay" model.  Currently you're assuming consecutive days, but what about weekends?  Seems like you'd need to add explicit dates for each day of the exam so just use an "Add Exam Day" button.  Then get rid of ExamDetails model.  Put that stuff in the Exam model.  So a course has one or many exams... an exam has one or many exam days.

Comment: Btw, personally I think it helps to draw a diagram of your database structure before writing a single line of code... or at least write down the table and field names.  You can work out a lot of stuff before you begin and there will be less re-writing of code (or migrations) down the road.

Comment: It just occurred to me that Course might have a CourseDays model.  If that was set ahead of time, you could do the date-range add.   Each exam day would be set to the uid of a specific course day. (aka "foreign key" for course day)

Comment: You need to break this down into smaller tasks, and try to implement each task. If you get stuck on a particular part, then show what you've tried, and explain what's not working about it.